# Firebase get comments from a startAt point javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to load comments starting from the last comment's loaded key.

Currently I am loading the first 2 comments like so:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/users/Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2/updates/MRKbUNMJ85xRVokRorf/comments')
  .limitToFirst(2).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      console.log(child.val().commentText);
    });
  });
```

Which works fine.

But I want to load the next 2 comments starting from the last comment's key.

In my actual code I find to last comment key, but for now lets just say:

```
var lastCommentKey = '-MRP79KPZRuaLHhBN8oZ';
```

Now I have tried all the below code, but each gives me no data:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/users/Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2/updates/MRKbUNMJ85xRVokRorf/comments')
  .limitToFirst(2).startAt(lastCommentKey).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      console.log(child.val().commentText);
    });
  });
```

Also tried using timestamp:

```
var lastCommentTimestamp = '1611051098364';
    
firebase.database().ref()
  .child("/users/Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2/updates/MRKbUNMJ85xRVokRorf/comments/")
  .orderByChild('commentTimestamp').limitToFirst(2).startAt(lastCommentTimestamp).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    ....
  });
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is my database layout:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2" : {
      "updates" : {
        "-MRKbUNMJ85xRVokRorf" : {
          "comments" : {
            "-MRKbXy6YJ0jFlOMPHWF" : {
              "commentText" : "comment 1",
              "commentTimestamp" : 1610975438244,
              "commentUser" : "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2"
            },
            "-MRP79KPZRuaLHhBN8oZ" : {
              "commentText" : "comment 2",
              "commentTimestamp" : 1611051098364,
              "commentUser" : "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2"
            },
            "-MRP87mkILia7YqAfyUO" : {
              "commentText" : "comment 3",
              "commentTimestamp" : 1611051354198,
              "commentUser" : "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2"
            },
            "-MRP9E5sgkpzEa4Mzhrj" : {
              "commentText" : "comment 4",
              "commentTimestamp" : 1611051642205,
              "commentUser" : "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2"
            },
            "-MRP9Iprrcx1-A2Hq4iH" : {
              "commentText" : "comment 5",
              "commentTimestamp" : 1611051661597,
              "commentUser" : "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2"
            }
          },
          "updateText" : "This is a test update",
          "updateTimestamp" : 1610975423540
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not ordering on anything yet. When using `limit` or `startAt`/`endAt` **always** specify a sort order for your query.

So for your initial query:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/users/Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2/updates/MRKbUNMJ85xRVokRorf/comments')
  .orderByKey().limitToFirst(2).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    ...
```

And then:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/users/Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2/updates/MRKbUNMJ85xRVokRorf/comments')
  .orderByKey().limitToFirst(2).startAt(lastCommentKey).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    ...
```